# Python Strings in Python Dictionary to Integers

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, integer

**is there any method to converts python dictionary with strings to python dictionary with corresponding integer arrays**

**Dictionary with String Arrays:**

```
 {1: '[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]',
 2: '[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]',
 3: '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]',
 4: '[24, 25, 26]'}
```

**Converted to Dictionary with corresponding Integer Arrays:**

```
{1: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
 2: [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
 3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 4: [24, 25, 26]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) we can loop over the dictionary and "cast" the string into their literals:

```
>>> import ast
>>> x =  {1: '[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]',
...  2: '[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]',
...  3: '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]',
...  4: '[24, 25, 26]'}
>>>
>>> {k: ast.literal_eval(v) for k,v in x.items()}
{1: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], 2: [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4: [24, 25, 26]}
```

Comment: Thank a lots, it really works with me